# I need to extract Data from a single line of json-data which is inbetween two variables (Powershell)

Tags: json, regex, powershell, escaping

I need to extract Data from a single line of json-data which is inbetween two variables (Powershell)

my Variables:
in front of Data:
DeviceAddresses":[{"Id":
after Data:
,"

I tried this, but there needs to be some error because of all the special characters I'm using:

```
$devicepattern = {DeviceAddresses":[{"Id":{.*?},"}
#$deviceid = [regex]::match($changeduserdata, $devicepattern).Groups[1].Value
#$deviceid
```

Comment: Note that JSON data is much easier to work with if you parse it into _objects_ whose properties you can access - see [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've found, some character literals can't be used as-is in a regex pattern because they carry special meaning - we call these *meta-characters*.

In order to match the corresponding character literal in an input string, we need to escape it with `\` -

- to match a literal `(`, we use the escape sequence `\(`,
- for a literal `}`, we use `\}`, and so on...

Fortunately, you don't need to know or remember which ones are meta-characters or escapable sequences - we can use `Regex.Escape()` to escape *all* the special character literals in a given pattern string:

```
$prefix = [regex]::Escape('DeviceAddresses":[{"Id":')
$capture = '(.*?)'
$suffix = [regex]::Escape(',"')
$devicePattern = "${prefix}${capture}${suffix}"
```

You also don't need to call `[regex]::Match` directly, PowerShell will populate the automatic `$Matches` variable with match groups whenever a scalar `-match` succeeds:

```
if($changeduserdata -match $devicePattern){
  $deviceid = $Matches[1]
} else {
  Write-Error 'DeviceID not found'
}
```

---

For reference, the following ASCII literals needs to be escaped in .NET's regex grammar:

```
$ ( ) * + . ? [ \ ^ { |
```

Additionally, `#` and   (regular space character) needs to be escaped and a number of other whitespace characters have to be translated to their respective escape sequences to make patterns safe for use with the [`IgnorePatternWhitespace` option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions?view=net-5.0#System_Text_RegularExpressions_RegexOptions_IgnorePatternWhitespace) (this is not applicable to your current scenario):

```
\u0009 => '\t'   # Tab
\u000A => '\n'   # Line Feed
\u000C => '\f'   # Form Feed
\u000D => '\r'   # Carriage Return
```

... all of which `Regex.Escape()` takes into account for you :)

Answer (score 2):

To complement [Mathias R. Jessen's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65109176/45375):

Generally, note that **JSON data is much easier to work with - and processed more robustly - if you parse it into *objects*** whose properties you can access - see the **bottom section**.

As for **your regex attempt**:

- Note: The following also applies to all *PowerShell-native* regex features, such as the `-match`, `-replace`, and `-split` [operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators), the [`switch` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Switch), and the [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) cmdlet.
- Mathias' answer uses **[`[regex]::Escape()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Escape)** to **escape the parts of the regex pattern to be used *verbatim*** by the regex engine.

  - This is **unequivocally the best approach if those *verbatim parts aren't known in advance*** - e.g., when provided via a variable or expression, or passed as an argument.
- However, in a **regex pattern that is specified as a string *literal*** it is often easier to ***individually* `\`-*escape* the regex metacharacters**, i.e. those characters that would otherwise have special meaning to the regex engine.

  - The **list of characters that need escaping** is (it can be *inferred* from the [.NET Regular-Expression Quick Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference)):

    - `\ ( ) | . * + ? ^ $ [ {`
    - *If* you enable the [`IgnorePatternWhiteSpace` option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions#System_Text_RegularExpressions_RegexOptions_IgnorePatternWhitespace) (which you can do inline with
      `(?x)`, at the start of a pattern), you'll additionally have to `\`-escape:

      - `#`
      - *significant* whitespace characters (those you actually want matched) specified *verbatim* (e.g., `' '`, or via string interpolation,`` "`t" ``); this does *not* apply to those specified via *escape sequences* (e.g., `\t` or `\n`).

Therefore, the solution could be simplified to:

```sh
# Sample JSON
$changeduserdata = '{"DeviceAddresses":[{"Id": 42,"More": "stuff"}]}'

# Note how [ and { are \-escaped
$deviceId = if ($changeduserdata -match 'DeviceAddresses":\[\{"Id":(.*?),"') {
  $Matches[1]
}
```

---

**Using [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json) to properly parse JSON into objects** is both more robust and more convenient, as it allows property access (dot notation) to extract the value of interest:

```sh
# Sample JSON
$changeduserdata = '{"DeviceAddresses":[{"Id": 42,"More": "stuff"}]}'

# Convert to an object ([pscustomobject]) and drill down to the property
# of interest; note that the value of .DeviceAddresses is an *array* ([...]).
$deviceId = (ConvertFrom-Json $changeduserdata).DeviceAddresses[0].Id  # -> 42
```