# In Powershell, How to -match $() in a string?

Tags: powershell

How to -match $() in a string?

```
    PS> $x = "base = `$(fixdir xyz)"

    PS> $x
    base = $(fixdir xyz)

    PS> $x -match "`$\(fixdir"
    False

    PS> $x -match "`$`(fixdir"
    parsing "$(fixdir" - Not enough )'s.
    At line:1 char:1
    + $x -match "`$`(fixdir"
    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: 
        (:) [], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException
```

Having trouble match $(fixdir  and getting a "True" from -match

```
    PS $x -match "..fixdir"
    True
```

True!  But, too easy to match other stuff..

Comment: `$` is a reserved regex character, so you have to escape it as `\$`

Comment: In short: In order for characters to be used _verbatim_ in a regex, those characters with special meaning (metacharacters) to the regex engine must be `\ `-escaped, which you can either do manually or programmatically with `[regex]::Escape()`; e.g. `'2\*2'` or `[regex]::Escape('2*2')`. See the linked duplicate for details.

Answer (score 3):

The escape sequence character in .NET's regex engine is `\`, but rather than manually escaping the string, you can use the [`Regex.Escape` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape) to automatically escape any problematic/special characters in a string literal you want to use as a pattern:

```
PS ~> $x = 'base = $(fixdir xyz)'
PS ~> $pattern = [regex]::Escape('$(fixdir')
PS ~> $x -match $pattern
True
```

Comment: Remember https://stackoverflow.com/a/65109176/45375? :) I do get the desire to provide a quick answer that comes easily to one, but I encourage you (and me) to be more mindful that duplicates often exist.

Comment: @mklement0 I wholeheartedly agree - but... you and I have ~9000 answers between us, I'm not gonna be able to remember all of them ^_^

Comment: I know it's cumbersome to look for duplicates, and much less fun than providing an answer, but I think the site is ultimately better off if we close outright duplicates as such. Personally, I use a note-taking application to keep track of "canonical" PowerShell answers, which can I find by keywords.

Answer (score 0):

```
PS> $x -match "\$\(fixdir"
True
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please "edit" to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: So it looks like you just needed to escape the special characters? If so, please highlight that in your answer for clarity.