# Powershell Set-Content fails for one file and succeeds for another?

Tags: powershell, replace

Trying to modify to different files and getting two different outcomes. The successful file "autoexec.cfg works fine. Here is the file contents and powershell code.
c:\temp\autoexec.cfg contains:

```
disable_write_track = true
webgui_port = 8470
```

powershell code to modify file:

```
$WGP = get-random -minimum 8000 -maximum 8999
$line = Get-Content "C:\temp\autoexec.cfg" | Select-String webgui_port | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Line
$content = Get-Content "C:\temp\autoexec.cfg"
$content | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace $line,"webgui_port = $WGP"} | Set-Content "C:\temp\autoexec.cfg"
```

The file that fails sets up like this.
c:\temp\serverSettings.lua contains:

```
cfg = 
{
    ["port"] = 10302,
} -- end of cfg
```

powershell code to modify file

```
$DCSP = get-random -minimum 10000 -maximum 19999
$line = Get-Content "C:\temp\serverSettings.lua" | Select-String port | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Line
$content = Get-Content "C:\temp\serverSettings.lua"
$content | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace $line,"    [\`"port\`"] = $DCSP,"} | Set-Content "C:\temp\serverSettings.lua"
```

The file does not change except it does. I have the file open in Notepadd++ and after running the code Notepad++ sees the file has been changed and wants to reload but there are no changes.

Comment: Closely related post with additional information, notably _manual_ escaping of regex metacharacters with `\ `: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65109086/45375

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-replace` is a regex operator, and `[]` is a special construct in a regular expression and needs to be escaped properly.

The easiest way to do that is with `[regex]::Escape()`:

```
$content | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace [regex]::Escape($line),"    [\`"port\`"] = $DCSP,"} | Set-Content "C:\temp\serverSettings.lua"
```

Comment: Thanks. I modified answer more but can't figure out how to properly format it to show up in this forum as it has escape characters. Basically removed the \'s around port.

Comment: @4evernoob for future reference, you can format string literals with verbatim backticks in comments by using _multiple_ backticks to qualify it, [like this](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/IISResetMe/43a6c3c74144e1c1feaf5d23c8b4bce5/raw/f492b69a55e3b2ea7e5cf13794613c82e835e883/gistfile1.txt)

Comment: Yes no backslashes